# How to return multiple values from a query vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

one question how to store or return multiple queries result values into multiple variables.. I'm using a query that return 4 columns but how to.. individual store those results into 4 separate variables.. here is my code

Private Sub FrmAlumnos_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtCurrentUser.Text = Login.txtUser.Text

```
    Dim strsql As String
    strsql = "SELECT ""Agregar"", ""Modificar"", ""Eliminar"", ""Imprimir"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""GrupoPantallas"" WHERE ""IdGrupo"" = (SELECT ""IdGrupo"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""Users"" WHERE ""IdUsers"" = '" _
        + Me.txtCurrentUser.Text + "') AND ""IdPantalla"" = '" + Me.Name + "'"
    Try
        Using conexion As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection(My.Settings.CNX_Principal)
            Dim comando As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand(strsql, conexion)
            conexion.Open()
            Dim registro As Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(0) = 0 Then
                btnNew.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(1) = 0 Then
                btnEdit.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(2) = 0 Then
                btnDelete.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(3) = 0 Then
                btnPrint.Visible = False
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm Using PostgreSQL just for you to know...

Comment: Why don't you make 4 queries?

Comment: Yes right know I have 4 queries one for each, but isn't there a way to do it in just one? thnx for reply

Comment: 1 query = 1 object. So, if you only want 1 query, you create an object, and then, you "split" this object into 4 new objects.

Comment: ExecuteReader returns a data reader.  Just use that.

Comment: but how do I compare the first element and then the second and then the third

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "SELECT ""Agregar"", ""Modificar"", ""Eliminar"", ""Imprimir"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""GrupoPantallas"" WHERE ""IdGrupo"" = (SELECT ""IdGrupo"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""Users"" WHERE ""IdUsers"" = '" _
    + Me.txtCurrentUser.Text + "') AND ""IdPantalla"" = '" + Me.Name + "'"
Try
    Using conexion As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection(My.Settings.CNX_Principal)
        Dim comando As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand(strsql, conexion)
        conexion.Open()
        Dim registro As Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader
        //This is the loop that you missed
        While registro.Read()
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(0) = 0 Then
                btnNew.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(1) = 0 Then
                btnEdit.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(2) = 0 Then
                btnDelete.Visible = False
            End If
            If comando.ExecuteReader.Item(3) = 0 Then
                btnPrint.Visible = False
            End If
        End While
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but all you have to do is loop through the DataReader as shown above.

Comment: But you're still sending 4 queries to the database when the ExecuteReader method is called!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I meant to change the line that says

`comando.ExecuteReader.Item(0) = 0`

To

`registro(0) = 0`

or whatever the field is that you're looking for. Basically...once you run the ExecuteReader, just use the reader object (`registro`) instead of calling "ExecuteReader" 4 times after that.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Mine, of course, is assuming that you are returning more than one record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find a DataSet to be useful here. Something like:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim com As New SqlCommand
com.Connection = <yourconnectionstring>
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text
com.CommandText = "YOURSQLSTUFF"
Dim da As New DataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = com

da.Fill(ds)
ds.Tables(0).TableName = "FirstTable"
ds.Tables(0).PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables(0).Columns("primaryKeyOfFirstTable")
ds.Tables(1).TableName = "SecondTable"
ds.Tables(1).PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables(1).Columns("primaryKeyOfSecondTable")
```

Hope that helps!

-sf

EDIT: After some more searching, I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr) link, which might help you out! It's  postgreSQL specific!

Comment: Of course...if postgreSQL doesn't support this kind of syntax then I guess it won't be of much use. Perhaps this could lead you on to do something similar!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Read method of the DataReader:

```
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "SELECT ""Agregar"", ""Modificar"", ""Eliminar"", ""Imprimir"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""GrupoPantallas"" WHERE ""IdGrupo"" = (SELECT ""IdGrupo"" FROM ""Seguridad"".""Users"" WHERE ""IdUsers"" = '" _
    + Me.txtCurrentUser.Text + "') AND ""IdPantalla"" = '" + Me.Name + "'"
Try
    Using conexion As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection(My.Settings.CNX_Principal)
        Dim comando As New Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand(strsql, conexion)
        conexion.Open()
        Using registro As Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader()
            //Assuming that there is only a single row returned
            If registro.Read()
                btnNew.Visible = registro.GetBoolean(0)
                btnEdit.Visible = registro.GetBoolean(1)
                btnDelete.Visible = registro.GetBoolean(2)
                btnPrint.Visible = registro.GetBoolean(3)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

You should also look into using parameters.  It would make the code a little cleaner than using a concatenated string and would stop sql injection attacks.